# Typescript using `__dirname` to reference local file

Tags: node.js, typescript

My file structure looks as follows:

```
root
  src
    test.ts
    template.xlsx
  dist
    // compiled js source ...
```

In `test.ts`, I try to reference the spreadsheet template as follows:

```
path.join(__dirname, "template.xlsx");
```

But it is searching in `path/to/root/dist` instead of looking in `path/to/root/src`. What's the best way to access my file?

Comment: you are doing it right, but you need to make sure that `template.xlsx` is also placed into `dist`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access to /src from /dist you could navigate there like this:

```
path.join(__dirname + "../src", "template.xlsx");
```